# How to add a null value on a list of <Offsets>? null cant be added because flutter null safety

Tags: flutter, offset, points, gesturedetector, custom-painter

I'm creating a drawing app using flutter. I've used gesturedetector onpanstart, onpanend, onpanupdate. But I have to close the array of offsets. Because of null safety I am not able to use 'null'. how can I add a null value on the List or end up the list somehow. or any other ways to make a drawing app using flutter.

```
onPanEnd:(details){setState((){drawingPoints.add(null!);});}
```

Comment: `final List<Offset?> list = [];
list.add(Offset(1,2));
list.add(null);`

Comment: null can't be added as a value of offset, because of flutter null safety added.

Comment: Facing the same issue, did you find any answer @dev-ruman

Answer (score 0):

To clear the available data in your `List` use `.clear()` or to assign a `null` value simply assign null to it

```
onPanEnd:(details){setState((){drawingPoints = null;});} // to assign null

onPanEnd:(details){setState((){drawingPoints.clear();});} // to clear the data
```

Comment: both are not working.

Comment: you need to show your full code because both are working for me, so you need to share your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy what you did with onPanStart , onPanUpdate , but in theonPanEnd instead of writing details.globalPosition just write Offset.infinite